# Replace `switch` and call child method based on property

Tags: typescript

I'm new to OOP. I have `calendar` with 3 `views` (for now). I have `abstract` class which simply creates `table` object, an `abstract` **CalendarTable** class which holds some setters and getters and `abstract` methods and a child class **Calendar** which overrides the base class methods. The problem is that every method has an `switch` which calls an `view's` method based on my property `currentView` where every view is `instantiated` in the **Calendar** constructor.

**Calendar**

```
export class Calendar extends my.core.calendar.CalendarTable {
        weeklyView: my.calendar.WeeklyView;
        monthlyView: my.calendar.MontlyView;
        dayView: my.calendar.DayView;

        constructor(cfg: my.core.calendar.iCalendarConfiguration) {
            super(cfg);

            this.weeklyView = new my.calendar.WeeklyView(this);
            this.monthlyView = new my.calendar.MontlyView(this);
            this.dayView = new my.calendar.DayView(this);
        }


        onResize(): void {
            /**
             *  Repaint all appointments on window resize
             *  For many reasons
             */
            this.bindAppointments();
        }

        createCalendar(): void {

            /** Clear everything on change */
            if (this.tBody.rows.length > 0) {
                this.tBody.clear();
                this.tHead.clear();
            }

            switch (this.config.currentView) {
                case "month":
                    this.monthlyView.createMontlyView();
                    break;
                case "day":
                    this.dayView.createDayView();
                    break;
                case "week":
                    this.weeklyView.createWeeklyView();
                    break;
            }

            this.bindAppointments();
        }

        bindAppointments(): void {
            this.clearAll();

            switch (this.config.currentView) {
                case "month":
                    this.monthlyView.bindMonthAppointments();
                    break;
                case "day":
                    this.dayView.bindDayAppointments();
                    break;
                case "week":
                    this.weeklyView.bindWeekAppointments();
                    break;
            }
        }

        Next(sender, e, data): void {
            switch (this.config.currentView) {
                case "month":
                    this.monthlyView.monthNavigationChange(true);
                    break;
                case "day":
                    this.dayView.dayNavigationChange(true);
                    break;
                case "week":
                    this.weeklyView.weekNavigationChange(true);
                    break;
            }
            this.createCalendar();
            this.updateLabels();
        }

        Previous(sender, e, data): void {
            switch (this.config.currentView) {
                case "month":
                    this.monthlyView.monthNavigationChange(false);
                    break;
                case "day":
                    this.dayView.dayNavigationChange(false);
                    break;
                case "week":
                    this.weeklyView.weekNavigationChange(false);
                    break;
            }
            this.createCalendar();
            this.updateLabels();
        }

        TabClick(sender: any, event: any, data: any): void {

            switch (sender.id.toLowerCase()) {
                case "day":
                    this.setActiveTab('day', event);
                    // update currentdate
                    break;
                case "month":
                    this.setActiveTab('month', event);
                    // update currentdate
                    break;
                case "week":
                    this.setActiveTab('week', event);
                    // update currentdate
                    break;
            }
            this.createCalendar();
            this.updateLabels();
        }


        updateLabels(): void {
            let date = new Date(this.config.currentDate);
            switch (this.config.currentView) {
                case "month":
                    this.currentDateMonth.value = String(this.calendar_months_label[date.getMonth()]) + ' ' + String(date.getFullYear());
                    break;
                case "day":
                    this.currentDateMonth.value = String(this.config.currentDate.getDate()) + ' ' + String(this.calendar_months_label[this.config.currentDate.getMonth()]) + ' ' + String(this.config.currentDate.getFullYear());
                    break;
                case "week":
                    this.currentDateMonth.value = String(this.getPreviousWeekStr(this.weekStart, this.weekEnd, this.calendar_months_label[this.config.currentDate.getMonth()], this.config.currentDate.getFullYear()));
                    break;
            }
        }
```

I think this is bad designed. My base user handlers are `TabClick, Next, Previous`. How can i make every `view` class to extend the **Calendar** and override his methods and when one of the handlers fires to call the appropriate view overrided method without having switch to determine whats my current view and call the instantiated class method?

Attaching one of the `view` classes to have an basic idea what every view class has. Other 2 has similar methods, just different render logic, calculations etc.

```
export class MontlyView {
        table: my.core.calendar.CalendarTable;

        EVENTS_DIV: string = 'cal-monthview-events-div';
        EVENTS_WRAPPER: string = 'cal-monthview-events-wrapper';

        TBODY_TD_DIV: string = 'cal-monthview-tbody-td-div';
        TBODY_TD_PREVIOUSORNEXTMONTH: string = 'cal-monthview-tbody-td-prevAndNextMonth';
        TBODY_TD_ISTODAY: string = 'cal-monthview-tbody-td-istoday';
        TBODY_TD_DISABLED: string = 'cal-monthview-tbody-td-disabled';
        TBODY_TD: string = 'cal-monthview-tbody-td';

        THEAD_TR: string = 'cal-monthview-thead-th';
        THEAD_TH: string = 'cal-monthview-thead-row';

        constructor(tbl: my.core.calendar.CalendarTable) {
            this.table = tbl;
        }

        private createMonthCellArray(day: number, nextMonth: boolean = undefined): Array<object> {
            let date = this.table.config.currentDate;

            if (nextMonth) {
                return [
                    {
                        startDate: new Date(new Date(date).getFullYear(), new Date(date).getMonth() + 1, day, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                        endDate: new Date(new Date(date).getFullYear(), new Date(date).getMonth() + 1, day, 23, 59, 59, 999)
                    }
                ]
            } else if (nextMonth == false) {
                return [
                    {
                        startDate: new Date(new Date(date).getFullYear(), new Date(date).getMonth() - 1, day, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                        endDate: new Date(new Date(date).getFullYear(), new Date(date).getMonth() - 1, day, 23, 59, 59, 999)
                    }
                ]
            } else {
                return [
                    {
                        startDate: new Date(new Date(date).getFullYear(), new Date(date).getMonth(), day, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                        endDate: new Date(new Date(date).getFullYear(), new Date(date).getMonth(), day, 23, 59, 59, 999),
                        isToday: new Date(new Date(date).getFullYear(), new Date(date).getMonth(), day).getTime() == new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).getTime() ? 1 : 0
                    }
                ]
            }
        }

        private attachSmallAppointment() {

        }

        private attachDisabledDays(j: number, el: HTMLElement, day: number): void {
            /**
             *  We have to check for startDate and endDate aswell because they may be all provided and we will apply
             *  the same class 2 times or more
             */
            for (let i = 0; i < this.table.config.disabledDays.length; i++) {
                if (this.table.config.startDate == null && this.table.config.endDate == null) {
                    if (j == this.table.config.disabledDays[i]) {
                        el.classList.add(this.TBODY_TD_DISABLED);
                    }
                } else if (this.table.config.startDate && this.table.config.endDate) {
                    if (day < this.table.config.startDate.getDate() || day > this.table.config.endDate.getDate()) {
                        el.classList.add(this.TBODY_TD_DISABLED);
                    }
                    if (j == this.table.config.disabledDays[i]) {
                        if (!this.table.checkClassContaining(el.classList, this.TBODY_TD_DISABLED)) {
                            el.classList.add(this.TBODY_TD_DISABLED);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (this.table.config.startDate && this.table.config.endDate == null) {
                    if (day < this.table.config.startDate.getDate()) {
                        el.classList.add(this.TBODY_TD_DISABLED);
                    }
                    if (j == this.table.config.disabledDays[i]) {
                        if (!this.table.checkClassContaining(el.classList, this.TBODY_TD_DISABLED)) {
                            el.classList.add(this.TBODY_TD_DISABLED);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (this.table.config.endDate && this.table.config.startDate == null) {
                    if (day > this.table.config.endDate.getDate()) {
                        el.classList.add(this.TBODY_TD_DISABLED);
                    }
                    if (j == this.table.config.disabledDays[i]) {
                        if (!this.table.checkClassContaining(el.classList, this.TBODY_TD_DISABLED)) {
                            el.classList.add(this.TBODY_TD_DISABLED);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private attachStartEndDateDisableClass(j: number, el: HTMLElement, day: number): void {
            /** Construct date based on the day so we can compare year month and date, not only date. */
            let currentIterationDate = new Date(this.table.config.currentDate.getFullYear(), this.table.config.currentDate.getMonth(), day);

            if (this.table.config.startDate && this.table.config.endDate) {
                if (currentIterationDate.getTime() < this.table.config.startDate.getTime() || currentIterationDate.getTime() > this.table.config.endDate.getTime()) {
                    el.classList.add(this.TBODY_TD_DISABLED);
                }
            } else if (this.table.config.startDate && this.table.config.endDate == null) {
                if (currentIterationDate.getTime() < this.table.config.startDate.getTime()) {
                    el.classList.add(this.TBODY_TD_DISABLED);
                }
            } else if (this.table.config.endDate && this.table.config.startDate == null) {
                if (currentIterationDate.getTime() > this.table.config.endDate.getTime()) {
                    el.classList.add(this.TBODY_TD_DISABLED);
                }
            }
        }

        public createMontlyView(): void {
            let self = this.table,
                 row: my.core.table.Row = new my.core.table.Row(this.table),
                 th: my.core.table.iCell,
                 td: my.core.table.tdCell,
                 finished = false,
                 day = 1,
                 nextMonthDay = 1,
                 previousMonthDayToStart;

            /** Reapply classes */
            this.table.element.className = "table table-bordered table-responsive col-sm-12 col-md-12 cal-monthview-table";

            /** Month view header */
            this.table.calendar_days_label.forEach((label, idx) => {
                th = new my.core.table.thCell();
                th.element.innerText = label;
                th.element.classList.add(this.THEAD_TH);
                row.addCell(th);
            });
            row.element.classList.add(this.THEAD_TR);
            this.table.tHead.addRow(row);

            /** Month view body */
            for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                row = new my.core.table.Row(this.table);
                for (let j = 0; j <= 6; j++) {
                    td = new my.core.table.tdCell();
                    /** add extra class for disabled days */
                    if (this.table.config.disabledDays.length > 0) {
                        this.attachDisabledDays(j, td.element, day);
                    } else if (this.table.config.startDate || this.table.config.endDate) {
                        this.attachStartEndDateDisableClass(j, td.element, day);
                    }

                    if (!this.table.checkClassContaining(td.element.classList, this.TBODY_TD_DISABLED)) {
                        /**
                             *  Bind cell click to the table config `cellClick` function
                             *  so it could be overrided if needed.
                             *  And only if it doesn contain class '*-disabled'
                             */
                        td.events.on.click(function (sender, e, data) {
                            self.config.cellClick(sender, e, data);
                        })
                    }

                    if (day <= this.table.monthLength && (i > 0 || j >= this.table.startingDay)) {
                        /**
                         *  Create empty div with the date related
                         *  and css class
                         */
                        td.element.appendChild(this.table.createDiv(day, this.TBODY_TD_DIV));
                        td.element.classList.add(this.TBODY_TD);
                        td.data = this.createMonthCellArray(day, undefined);

                        /** Append new css class if the flag isToday == 1 */
                        if (td.data[0]['isToday'] === 1) {
                            td.element.classList.add(this.TBODY_TD_ISTODAY);
                        }
                        row.addCell(td);

                        day++;
                    } else {
                        if (!finished) {
                            /** If it's January get the December previous year days */
                            if (new Date(this.table.config.currentDate).getMonth() === 0 && previousMonthDayToStart == null) {
                                previousMonthDayToStart = this.table.calendar_days_in_month[this.table.calendar_days_in_month.length - 1] - this.table.startingDay;
                            } else if (previousMonthDayToStart == null) {
                                previousMonthDayToStart = this.table.calendar_days_in_month[new Date(this.table.config.currentDate).getMonth() - 1] - (this.table.startingDay - 1);
                            }
                            td.element.classList.add(this.TBODY_TD_PREVIOUSORNEXTMONTH);

                            /**
                             *  If day is greater than month length and the flag `finished` is false
                             *  Then we have to get the next month length and render it.
                             */
                            if (day > this.table.monthLength) {
                                td.element.appendChild(this.table.createDiv(nextMonthDay, this.TBODY_TD_DIV));
                                td.data = this.createMonthCellArray(nextMonthDay, true);
                                nextMonthDay++;
                            } else {

                                td.element.appendChild(this.table.createDiv(previousMonthDayToStart, this.TBODY_TD_DIV));
                                td.data = this.createMonthCellArray(previousMonthDayToStart, false);
                                previousMonthDayToStart++;
                            }
                            row.addCell(td);
                        }
                    }
                    /** Stop creating rows */
                    if (day > this.table.monthLength && j == 6) {
                        finished = true;
                    }
                }
                this.table.tBody.addRow(row);
            }
        }

        public monthNavigationChange(next: boolean): void {
            let month = new Date(this.table.config.currentDate).getMonth(),
                 year = new Date(this.table.config.currentDate).getFullYear();

            if (next) {
                if (month == 11) {
                    month = 0;
                    this.table.config.currentDate = new Date(year + 1, month);
                    this.table.MonthLength = month;
                } else {
                    month += 1;
                    this.table.config.currentDate = new Date(year, month);
                    this.table.MonthLength = month;
                }
            } else if (!next) {
                if (month == 0) {
                    month = 11;
                    this.table.config.currentDate = new Date(year - 1, month);
                    this.table.MonthLength = month;
                } else {
                    month -= 1;
                    this.table.config.currentDate = new Date(year, month);
                    this.table.MonthLength = month;
                }

            }
        }

        public bindMonthAppointments(): void {
            let eventsContainer = this.table.createDiv('', this.EVENTS_WRAPPER, 'events'),
                self = this.table,
                _datesOffset: Array<object> = [],
                toPrint = false;

            if (this.table.appointments) {

                for (let i = 0; i < this.table.appointments.length; i++) {
                    this.table.tBody.rows.forEach((rowObj, rowIdx) => {
                        rowObj.cells.forEach((cellObj, cellIdx) => {
                            /* Set time to 0 so we can compare date and month only */
                            let appDate = new Date(new Date(this.table.appointments[i]['startDate']).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)),
                                cellDate = new Date(new Date(cellObj['data'][0]['startDate']).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));

                            if (appDate.getTime() == cellDate.getTime()) {
                                let cell = rowObj.cells[cellIdx].element,
                                    eventApp,
                                    appCounter;

                                /* we have to keep track of the previous element's offsetleft for the same time */
                                if (!this.table.isDateInArray(this.table.appointments[i]['startDate'], _datesOffset)) {
                                    /* Start render at about 35% of the cell height (or almost center) */
                                    _datesOffset.push(
                                        {
                                            startDate: new Date(new Date(this.table.appointments[i]['startDate']).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)),
                                            offsetTop: cell.offsetTop + (cell.offsetHeight * 0.33),
                                            eventCounter: 0
                                        }
                                    )
                                }
                                /* We found the f app, now render it */
                                let eventDimension = {
                                    transformX: cell.offsetLeft,
                                    transformY: '', // overrided 
                                    w: cell.offsetWidth,
                                    h: cell.offsetHeight / 3,
                                    bColor: this.table.appointments[i]['Color'],
                                }
                                /* Override offsetTop */
                                if (_datesOffset.length > 0) {
                                    _datesOffset.forEach((obj, idx) => {
                                        if (new Date(obj['startDate']).getTime() == new Date(new Date(this.table.appointments[i]['startDate']).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).getTime()) {
                                            eventDimension['transformY'] = obj['offsetTop'];
                                            obj['offsetTop'] += cell.offsetHeight * 0.33;
                                            obj['eventCounter'] += 1;

                                            appCounter = obj['eventCounter'];
                                        }
                                    })
                                }
                                if (appCounter <= 2) {
                                    eventApp = new my.controls.cAppointment(this.EVENTS_DIV, eventDimension);
                                    /* InnerHTML like that , because someone may want to override it outside */
                                    eventApp.element.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', this.table.config.appointmentTemplate(this.table.appointments[i]));
                                    eventApp.element.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
                                        self.config.appointmentClick(self.appointments[i], ev)
                                    });
                                    eventsContainer.appendChild(eventApp.element);
                                } else {
                                    /* create small block which shows all other appointments on button popup */
                                    this.attachSmallAppointment();
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    })
                }
            }
            this.table.element.parentElement.appendChild(eventsContainer);
        }
    } /** end monthly view */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a common interface for all views and hold the current view instance in a member of the class:

```
interface IView {
    create();
    bindAppointments();
    navigationChange(next: boolean);
}
export class Calendar extends my.core.calendar.CalendarTable {
    currentView: IView; // Set this when the current view changes,

    bindAppointments(): void {
       this.clearAll();
       this.currentView.bindAppointments();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the question, but I'm keeping the `currentView` in an object which represents the configuration of my calendar, when i update it how should i `set` the `currentView: IView` so it will call the exact view logic?

Comment: That is up to you, personally I would firstly set it in the constructor based on the config. Any change in the configuration would not be reflected back to the `currentView` field, but I would also add a method on the calendar class `setCurrentView(view: "day"| "year" | "month"): void` that updates the `currentView` field and maybe the `string` field in the config (depending on weather the config is not reusable amongst several calendars)\

Comment: but in this method `setCurrentView` i still rely on `switch` but atlest it will be one in the whole code i guess.

Comment: Yes, you would still need a switch there. If you don't plan to change views, you can just pass an `IView` in the config and use that.

Comment: Yeah, i learned something new and useful in OOP, thank you very much :)

Comment: Also you don't necessarily need a switch, you could have a member `supportedViews: { [key: string] : IView } =  { week: new my.calendar.WeeklyView(), day : new my.calendar.DayView() ...  }` and use indexing to get to the view `this.supportedViews[viewName]`

Comment: I just tried it and its really nice approach, but since i see it for first time, how is this `{ [key: string]: IView = { ... }` thing called so i can read more about it?

Comment: It's called an index signature, a quick explanation you can fin here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/index-signatures.html

Comment: Thank you! I have one last question, when i instantiate any view class I'm passing `this` to their constructor where `this` is my top class (which creates the table object), is there a way to pass in the view constructor the `Calendar` class so the views can have access to the `Calendar` class methods and the abstract class methods aswell? Right now i have access to the abstract `CalendarTable` methods but i want to some of the methods to be in the `Calendar` class without having to create `abstract` method in `CalendarTable` and override it in `Calendar` ?

Comment: Just change the type of the field and the constructor parameter of the view to `Calendar`. Passing `this` is a valid approach, you are just using the wrong type.